# ошибка net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE при соеденении WebSocket

Tags: python, websocket, ssl

файлы сертификата теже что в nginx - сам сайт работает - и проблем не вызывает - tentacula.ru

проблема появилась сегодня с утра на всех сайтах, где я использую сертификаты "Let's Encrypt" - на сайте - myfalke.ru( я заменил сертификаты для сокетов на покупные, проблема пропала)

проблема только с подключением WebSocket( wss://tentacula.ru:9296/ws/) - самого подключения нету в логах - оно просто не доходит до него

обновил сертификаты - это не помогло =(

где копать - может кто столкнулся с этим?

для сокетов использую - AIOHTTP, для всего остального nginx

опять же повторюсь: вчера все работало - перестало сегодня утром на всех сайтах ((((

вариант ошибка в коде - это очень маленькая вероятность - сайты на разных серверах, в том числе тех, что я уже как месяц не залезал

сделал еще https://tentacula.ru:9296/ ( чтоб проверить сам веб сервер) - на входе от хрома получаю -  NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Вот кода(вдруг поможет):

```
if self.args.ssl:
  self.debug(u"SSL: {0}".format(self.args.ssl))
  ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
  ssl_context.load_cert_chain(certfile=self.args.certfile, keyfile=self.args.keyfile)
else:
  ssl_context = None

application.router.add_route('GET', '/', hello)
application.router.add_route('GET', '/ws/{uri:.*}', websocket_handler)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
handler = application.make_handler()

run_param = {
    'protocol_factory' : handler
  , 'host': address
  , 'port': port
  , 'ssl': ssl_context
}
f = loop.create_server(**run_param)

try:
  srv = loop.run_until_complete(f)
except:
  error = commonFunction.getExceptionError()
```

Comment: чем вопросы отличаются? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/796667/23044

Comment: там я думал что проблема в веб сокете - оказалась просто проблема в сертификате